# Para usar HibernateStatistics é obrigatorio criar um hibernate.cfg.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate

Achei sem sentido, ja que geralmente as configuracoes do hibernate ficam alocadas no xml persistence.

Da pra recuperar a sessionfactory so usando as configuracoes do hibernate alocadas no persistence.xml ? ou preciso replicar as configuracoes de ORM pro hibernate.cfg.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir da JPA 2.1 você pode recuperar a `SessionFactory` da seguinte maneira:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema!